# Xcode 6.0.1 poor performance

Tags: xcode6

I noticed that Xcode 6.0.1 has poor performance. Checked with Terminal command, here is the result:

```
~ MY_USERNAME$ ps aux | head
USER             PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
MY_USERNAME      496  99.9 17.3 28817056 1454748   ??  R    10:06AM  30:44.60 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Overlays/Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool --socketFD 37
```

When I work on storyboard, it occupied all my CPU power for all the time Xcode is running. The storyboard only contains few empty View Controllers only. Moreover, simulator works very slowly in Xcode 6, compared to Xcode 5. Does anyone have solution to solve this performance issue?

Using Xcode 6.0.1 (build 6A317), Mac OS X 10.9.5, 8GB RAM, 2.8GHz i7 CPU

Comment: No solutions I'm afraid @Raptor but I've been getting this bizarre CPU use as well. Even duplicating a simple view can take 20 seconds.

Comment: End up I found a temporary solution: Take the above process as example (which persists even Xcode is completely quitted), I kill it with `kill 496` command in Terminal. Then, re-open Xcode, the problem is gone for a while. Repeat this if it appears again (note the PID will change)

Comment: I filed a bug, because the storyboard crashed, after inserting an AV Controller.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: open your storyboard and disable and re-enable autolayout (in file inspector).

Comment: This will remove all the Auto Layout constraints. All layouts will be broken.

Comment: Thanks @Ty Le this appears to have fixed it for me (probably temporarily). I'm using a Wacom Intuos which is also a factor in the problem.